# save a variable to file which name defined by user - matlab

Tags: file, matlab, save

I want to save a matrix into a file, therefore I'm using

```
dlmwrite('matrix', m);
```

But I want save the file using a save file dialog just like using [uiputfile](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uiputfile.html) but, I dont think it can

Is there any other ways to do something similar to it? or I'm just missing something from the [dlmwrite](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dlmwrite.html) function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use uiputfile for this:

```
[file,path] = uiputfile('*.csv','Save file');
csvwrite([path file], m);
```

the `uiputfile` command doesn't save anything, it just returns the name and path of the selected file. See [this](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/uiputfile.html).